# Networking in Kali VM

Tags: kali-linux

I currently have Kali installed on a virtual machine in a Macbook using VirtualBox. Is there a way to configure Kali or VirtualBox to recognise the Macbook's wireless card as it's own wireless card? When installed, Kali automatically recognises the Macbook's wireless card as a wired connection. So I want to change that wired connection to a wireless one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Open VM settings

2.) Navigate to the Network heading

3.) Choose your adapter

4.) Pick Bridged Adapter from the name dropdown menu

Note: this will not show up as a wireless connection but you will be attached to the host's adapter in this case the WLAN card. If you NEED a wireless connection, you must use a USB device, and attach it to the virtual machine from the menu. Once inside Kali run `ifconfig` and the USB wifi adapter should appear. More details can be found in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K1ETBeRQBs4&feature=youtu.be).